# Error and Build Failed while setting up mediapipe on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian OS 64 bit)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mediapipe

I am new to both Raspberry Pi and Mediapipe. I was following these steps: https://spyjetson.blogspot.com/2021/06/installing-mediapipecpu-mode-on.html

But on this step: root@raspberrypi:/usr/local/src/mediapipe# python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

I am getting error and build failed

Error is this:

```
ERROR: /usr/local/src/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/stream_handler/BUILD:95:11: C++ compilation of rule '//mediapipe/framework/stream_handler:default_input_stream_handler' failed (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 55 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 55 argument(s) skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
In file included from <command-line>:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Functor, class, class> std::function<std::unique_ptr<mediapipe::InputStreamHandler>(std::shared_ptr<mediapipe::tool::TagMap>, mediapipe::CalculatorContextManager*, const mediapipe::MediaPipeOptions&, bool)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = <missing>; <template-parameter-1-2> = <missing>; <template-parameter-1-3> = <missing>]':
mediapipe/framework/stream_handler/default_input_stream_handler.cc:24:1:   required from here
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:32:94: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   32 |    whether the overall intent is to support these features; otherwise,
      |                                                                                              ^                         
0x7fa3cab217 __libc_start_main
    ../csu/libc-start.c:308
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Target //mediapipe/modules/face_detection:face_detection_short_range_cpu failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 853.907s, Critical Path: 792.14s
INFO: 990 processes: 130 internal, 860 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a GCC issue. I downgraded from 10 to 9 and it compiled.

```
sudo apt install gcc-9 g++-9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-9
```